# Removing double quotes- Excel to Notepad

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have written a macro to dump excel cells on to a notepad file. The cell contents appear along with a " in the .txt file. How do I get rid of the double quotes before writing it to the file?

```
Sub makeFile1()

    Dim ce As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Open "C:\queries.txt" For Output As #1
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          Write #1, "Create Table " & ws.Name
            For Each ce In Range("G2:G10")
               If ce.Next = "" Then
               Write #1, ce.Value
               ElseIf ce.Value <> "" Then
               Write #1, ce.Value & ","
               End If

            Next ce
    Next ws
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Print #1` instead of `Write #1`

```
Sub makeFile1()
Dim ce As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Open "C:\queries.txt" For Output As #1
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      Print #1, "Create Table " & ws.Name
        For Each ce In Range("G2:G10")
           If ce.Next = "" Then
           Print #1, ce.Value
           ElseIf ce.Value <> "" Then
           Print #1, ce.Value & ","
           End If

        Next ce
Next ws
Close #1

End Sub
```